# Database on secondary replica cannot join availability group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

I am trying to add a database to an Availability Group Always On. I already have the other two DBs working fine on the same SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition Cluster (running on Windows 2016 Standard).

When joining the secondary DB to the AG the database ends up in Not Synchronizing / Recovery pending state. I followed different online sources with alternative solutions without any success.

Has anyone else experienced a similar situation? Any suggestions?

Comment: What method are you using to add it to the AG? Direct seeding, Full database and log backup? Also check your sql logs for any errors

Comment: Hi Gabe, [these steps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/243616/185080) must help in your case. If you have already done so, you probably got to post your finding part of the question.

Comment: I have tried all options; for the first two all checks are green, but the secondary does not join, hanging in the Not synchronizing / Recovery Pending status.

Comment: Hi Gabe, could you please elaborate on what you mean by 'the other two DBs working fine'? Do you mean 1 DB primary and secondary? Or 2 separate DBs? According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2016), Availability Groups on Standard Edition only support one availability database.

Comment: Hi Rich, maybe I did not find the right words; I have three Availability Groups, each one handling one database. Two are working fine and actually I did not have any problem setting them up. I used exactly same steps for all three AG but this last one is giving me a really hard time. Any suggestion or recommendation that may help would be welcome. Thank you, Gabe

Comment: Check this: https://www.sqlserverblogforum.com/alwayson/alwayson-database-not-synchronized-and-recovery-pending/